# Delete cookies in webBrowser without restart

Tags: c#, cookies, browser, webbrowser-control

Can you say how I can delete all cookies in `private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser webBrowser1`. I used

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool InternetSetOption(IntPtr hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int lpdwBufferLength);
```

I want do this with button click.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
}
```

But it doesn't work. And I know about 
`webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:void((function(){var a,b,c,e,f;f=0;a=document.cookie.split('; ');for(e=0;e<a.length&&a[e];e++){f++;for(b='.'+location.host;b;b=b.replace(/^(?:%5C.|[^%5C.]+)/,'')){for(c=location.pathname;c;c=c.replace(/.$/,'')){document.cookie=(a[e]+'; domain='+b+'; path='+c+'; expires='+new Date((new Date()).getTime()-1e11).toGMTString());}}}})())");`
It isn't suitable for me.

Comment: This may work but it's undocumented: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17369275/1768303. This may also help, depending on your goals: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21254020/1768303.

Comment: I do not quite understand where I should put dynamic `document=webBroweser.Document;
document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache", false);` Inside my button??  I get Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException in System.Core.dll

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument does not contain a definition for "execCommand"

Comment: You forgot `dynamic` keyword: `dynamic document=webBroweser.Document;`. There is no *hard-typed* `execCommand` method, unless you use MSHTML PIA.

Comment: I forgot it only in this comment.

Comment: I can't tell why you're seeing this error. Is `webBrowser.Document == null`? Does `webBrowser.Document.Body.OuterHtml` throw too?

Comment: I understand, it can't help.

Answer (score 5):

the correct typing is as follows:

```
dynamic document = webBrowser1.Document;
document.ExecCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache", false, null);
```

Cheers.

Comment: Does not work with .Net 4.5 and Facebook Login flow.